# why does website change based on use of www?

Tags: html

been working on my website for last couple of days- and for some reason everything scales differently based on wheather or not i use the www prefix on my webpage. What is causing this and how is it even possible if its the same file? this never happened with my old page setup

Comment: Please show some examples of what you mean by "scales".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is that you have accidentally changed the zoom level in your browser, and the zoom setting is saved per domain. `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` are treated as different sites internally in your browser.

Check out the zoom level settings and try to reset them.

Comment: e.g. pressing `CTRL+0` in FF.

Comment: wow- that seems odd that it would save per domain, i always figured the zoome was only temp saved to the current tab.

i was trying to google this problem for half an hour and the keywords www were getting me nowhere hah. thanks that seems to have been the issue